# File java.lang.NullPointerException. error

Tags: java, file, exception, nullpointerexception, directory

I have the following code below, which is used to list all the files within specific folders/directories.

For mac this works perfectly, but when it comes to windows I get a java.lang.NullPointerException. I am not completely sure how I would fix it, I am aware that it means one of the directory File variables are passed as Null when being put into the function. But I am not sure how to check whether the directory is null and why exactly it creates an error on only that particular directory as it works on all the other directories and the directory it doesn't work on is just the regular documents directory on Windows. I have made a small comment on the three lines where the java.lang.NullPointerException error is showing.

I have also tried to fix it by surrounding the file list function to check whether the folder is null or not. But that doesn't work as it is already to late, the null error is already happening at the File variable declaration.

```
public static void main() throws IOException {

        if (isMac()) {
            listFilesForFolderMac(folderMac1);
            listFilesForFolderMac(folderMac2);
            listFilesForFolderMac(folderMac3);
            listFilesForFolderMac(folderMac4);
            listFilesForFolderMac(folderMac5);
            listFilesForFolderMac(folderMac6);
            listFilesForFolderMac(folderMac7);
        } else if (isWindows()) {
            listFilesForFolderWin(folderWin1);
            listFilesForFolderWin(folderWin2);
            listFilesForFolderWin(folderWin3);
            listFilesForFolderWin(folderWin4);
            listFilesForFolderWin(folderWin5);
            listFilesForFolderWin(folderWin6);
        }

    }

    public static boolean isWindows() {
        return (OS.indexOf("win") >= 0);
    }

    public static boolean isMac() {
        return (OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0);
    }

public static void listFilesForFolderMac(final File folder) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writToDoc = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("/Users/" + username + "/Documents/files.txt",true));
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolderMac(fileEntry);
            } else {
                writToDoc.println(fileEntry.getName());
            }
        }
        writToDoc.close();
    }

    public static void listFilesForFolderWin(final File folder) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writToDoc = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\users\\" + username + "\\Documents\\files.txt",true));
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) { //Error here
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                    listFilesForFolderWin(fileEntry); //Error here
            } else {
                writToDoc.println(fileEntry.getName());
            }
        }
        writToDoc.close();
    }

    final static File folderMac1 = new File("/Users/" + username + "/Pictures");
    final static File folderMac2 = new File("/Users/" + username + "/Documents");
    final static File folderMac3 = new File("/Users/" + username + "/Movies");
    final static File folderMac4 = new File("/Users/" + username + "/Music");
    final static File folderMac5 = new File("/Users/" + username + "/Downloads");
    final static File folderMac6 = new File("/Users/" + username + "/Applications");
    final static File folderMac7 = new File("/Users/" + username + "/Desktop");


    final static File folderWin1 = new File("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Desktop");
    final static File folderWin2 = new File("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Downloads");
    final static File folderWin3 = new File("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Documents"); //Error here
    final static File folderWin4 = new File("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Pictures");
    final static File folderWin5 = new File("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Music");
    final static File folderWin6 = new File("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Videos");
```

I get the following error stated below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at script.MyClass.listFilesForFolderWin(MyClass.java:200)
    at script.MyClass.listFilesForFolderWin(MyClass.java:202)
    at script.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:155)
```

Comment: try stepping through this code and debugging it

Comment: You never check to see if the `File` reference is actually a directory or not.  Some "directories" in Windows are a type of symbolic link, which isn't supported by the `File` API

Comment: * never check to see if the value been past to `listFilesForFolderWin` is a directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some folders in Windows that Java can see but not see into, and some files that it sees as directories. To solve your problem, simply check before you try to list the files:

```
if (fileEntry.isDirectory()&&fileEntry.listFiles()!=null) {
    listFilesForFolderWin(fileEntry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have messed around with the file commands that Java has, and usually when you get a NullPointerExcpetion, it means that the directory you have given it is wrong. I have not run your code on windows, but for that platform, all you need to do is follow the same file structure that you did with your Mac paths. Here is what your first variable should be:

`final static File folderWin1 = new File("C:/Users/" + username + "/Pictures");`

All of the rest of your variables should follow the same structure. I hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: I really appreciate the input, but after trying, it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.File` can not process Window's "junction"s (a type of symbolic link), such as "My Documents" and "Pictures"

You will need to switch over to the NIO2 API and make use of the `Paths` API.

See [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) which actually has an example for processing symbolic links

*Extract from above link*

```
@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                               BasicFileAttributes attr) {
    if (attr.isSymbolicLink()) {
        System.out.format("Symbolic link: %s ", file);
    } else if (attr.isRegularFile()) {
        System.out.format("Regular file: %s ", file);
    } else {
        System.out.format("Other: %s ", file);
    }
    System.out.println("(" + attr.size() + "bytes)");
    return CONTINUE;
}
```

You may also want to have a look at [Links, Symbolic or Otherwise](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html) for more details

Comment: I ended up using one of the other answers, however this answer has some rather interesting information, of which I didn't know. The "heads up" is very much appreciated, thank you.